# IGlobalInterfaceTable::RegisterInterfaceInGlobal returns zero cookie

Tags: windows, com, reverse-engineering, apimonitor, com-automation

I'm trying to repackage a proprietary app that consists of several libraries, COM interfaces and a COM automation server.

My stripped down distribution doesn't work.

Using the function call monitor (RohitLab API monitor), I've established that a call to 
IGlobalInterfaceTable::RegisterInterfaceInGlobal returns a zero value for the cookie in the stripped version; while in the correct full install, it always returns 256.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/windows/desktop/ms682465(v=vs.85).aspx) says that "The value of an invalid cookie is 0."

It is very interesting, but the application ignores the zero return value and uses 256 instead (always?) for IGlobalInterfaceTable::GetInterfaceFromGlobal, and doesn't work later, because it's trying to connect the NULL pointer returned for the interface to other COM objects.

It doesn't crash though, just wouldn't work as expected.

Question:
Why would RegisterInterfaceInGlobal return a zero value? The dll which contains type library for this interface is registered using regsvr32. Btw, it seems to load another dll which is also a COM library, but without a type library in it.

Comment: Well, that does not make any sense.  A 0 does not turn magically into 256.  A simple explanation is that the api monitor is buggy, showing the value *before* the call instead of after the call.  Keep looking, this isn't it.

Comment: Hans, I have two identical Windows virtual machines. One of them runs a full installation, and the API monitor does show the post-call value (which is always 256).
I think that a lousy developer hard-coded 256, because that's what he always got during experiments, and that's the only interface that's ever registered in GIT, so it is repeatable and didn't cause any trouble.
I'll try disassembling the function call to confirm this.

Comment: Also, in the broken installation the post-call value of interface object pointer is not changed, it stays NULL. I'm pretty sure it's because of the broken install, not a bug in the monitor.

Comment: Update: not the only interface ever registered, it just always goes first.